# FFMPEG: audio out of sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, synchronization

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://.............." -re -stream_loop -1 -i audio.m4a -filter_complex "[0:a]highpass=f=200,lowpass=f=3000,volume=0.3[mic];[1:a]volume=0.1[mic2];[mic][mic2]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -b:a 320k -c:a aac -f flv "rtmp://......."`

This is my working very well script thanks to @Ilogan

But now i have a problem with an audio out of sync, i don't care about the second one, its just a file audio but the first one is from a microphone of camera IP so it should be synced with the video but now the sound from a microphone is almost 28 seconds later.

Any tips how to do it?

`adelay=28000` ? - nope, that didnt help since i need to delay the video to sync this with an audio.Also tried `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` but it didnt help neither.
Also i used -itsoffset 28 it helped but for a while, looks like that the delay time between video and audio is rising and now its 40sec+
Whats going on?

Now i'm trying with `tpad=start_duration=28`

edit:

````
  Metadata:
    title           : NVT
    comment         : From NVT
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080, 5 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    title           : Nature
    artist          : 
    date            : 2018
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    comment         : 
  Duration: 08:20:49.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 01/28/2020.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_mulaw) -> highpass
  Stream #1:0 (aac) -> volume
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  amix -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x82e490] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://....':
  Metadata:
    title           : NVT
    comment         : From NVT
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 5 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=    7 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     572kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=10634.7kbitsframe=   13 fps= 13 q=-1.0 size=     697kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate=6463.4kbits/frame=   25 fps= 16 q=-1.0 size=    1185kB time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=6533.1kbits/frame=   33 fps= 16 q=-1.0 size=    1390kB time=00:00:01.99 bitrate=5702.1kbits```
````

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.

Comment: ```frame=201651 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size= 4177810kB time=02:34:08.59 bitrate=3700.5kbitsframe=201660 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size= 4178009kB time=02:34:09.09 bitrate=3700.5kbitsframe=201757 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size= 4180304kB time=02:34:14.16 bitrate=3700.5kbitsframe=201766 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size= 4180492kB time=02:34:14.64 bitrate=3700.5kbitsframe=201776 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size= 4180702kB time=02:34:15.16 bitrate=3700.5kbits/s speed=   1x
```
You mean this? There are no any errors.

Comment: No, that's just part of it. Run the command for about 10 seconds, then copy all of the text it outputs. [Edit] your question and paste the text.

Comment: done but i didnt know how to copy all of the text but i think most of it is there.

Comment: Still missing stuff. Add `-y -t 10` to the command and append `2> ff.log` to the end. Run the command and look for `ff.log`.

Comment: Have you tried it without the second audio file input?  Is it still out of sync?